# I want to remove the item that is selected checkbox from the gridview, how should i do in order to remove it from the arraylist

Tags: android

I have an application that shows a grid view of a list of pictures with a checkbox, and I have a button that will delete the selected checkbox and relative picture from the application. I don't need to delete the item from the localhost server, but just only from the application runtimes. I've tried to save the checkbox checked item position to a list and remove it with a for loop but it shows an unsupportedOperationException.
Any way for me to solve this problem?

Adapter.java

\\

```
package com.example.assignment4task2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private Context viewContext;
    private List<WebsiteLocation> websiteLocations;
    private List<WebsiteLocation> selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private ImageButton button;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    GridAdapter adapter = this;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, List<WebsiteLocation> websiteLocations, ImageButton imagebutton){
        this.context = context;
        this.websiteLocations = websiteLocations;
        this.button = imagebutton;

    }

    public void removeItem(WebsiteLocation position){
        websiteLocations.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return websiteLocations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        viewContext = parent.getContext();
        WebsiteLocation webLocation = websiteLocations.get(position);
        System.out.println(webLocation);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewContext).inflate(R.layout.image_layout,parent,false);

        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ImageLoader imageLoader = Singleton.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(webLocation.getThumbnail(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
                Bitmap thumbnail_bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,300,300);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail_bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(webLocation.getThumbnail());

                Toast.makeText(viewContext,"Failed to load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    System.out.println("timeout error");
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    System.out.println("Connection error");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    System.out.println("AuthFailure error");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    System.out.println("Server error");
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    System.out.println("Network error");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    System.out.println("Parse error");
                }
            }
        });

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                    selectedImages.add(websiteLocations.get(position));
                    System.out.println(selectedImages);
                }
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(context, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("weblocation",webLocation);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (WebsiteLocation si: selectedImages) {
                    removeItem(si);
                }
            }
        });








        return view;
    }


}

\\\
```

mainactivity.java

```
\\\
package com.example.assignment4task2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gridView;
    private WebsiteLocation[] websiteLocations;
    private List<WebsiteLocation> websiteLocationList;
    private GridAdapter adapter;
    private ImageButton imagebutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        imagebutton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        websitelocatoinsArray();
        websiteLocationList = Arrays.asList(websiteLocations);
        adapter = new GridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), websiteLocationList,imagebutton);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);




    }

    private void websitelocatoinsArray(){
        websiteLocations = new WebsiteLocation[]{
                new WebsiteLocation("Germany", "http://192.168.1.100/image/germany_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/germany.png"),
                new WebsiteLocation("Indonesia","http://192.168.1.100/image/indonesia_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/indonesia.png"),
                new WebsiteLocation("Japan","http://192.168.1.100/image/japan_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/japan.png"),
                new WebsiteLocation("Sarawak","http://192.168.1.100/image/sarawak_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/sarawak.png"),
                new WebsiteLocation("Singapore","http://192.168.1.100/image/singapore_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/singapore.png"),
                new WebsiteLocation("Switzerland","http://192.168.1.100/image/switzerland_thumb.png","http://192.168.1.100/image/switzerland.png")


        };
    }
}
```

\\

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use room to store your data at runtime and retrieve your data from room DB once you do that you will be able to create a method to delete the selected item from the room DB.

Comment: i dont need to delete it from the database, just need to delete it from the screen. Ive try to use a list to store the position and delete the position but android shows errors